# How to get out of infinite loop?

Tags: loops, infinite-loop, labview

I want to make in LabView a game similar to this: [memory game](http://www.web-games-online.com/memory/)

but I get stuck in a infinite loop and do not know how to get out.
This is what I have so far :[image: Block diagram]

This is a piece of code for two of the buttons. In my opinion there are only 3 possible cases (bt1 and bt2 are the identical buttons):

1. Both bt1 and bt2 are pressed and they disappear (first part of the photo)
2. Just one of the two buttons was pressed, but also another button was pressed and the buttons go back to the initial color (middle part of the photo)
3. Just one of the two buttons was pressed and it is the only button pressed, so it must stay pressed until another button is pressed (last part of the photo)

The 'once' variable indicates if another button was pressed before (0-was not pressed before ; 1- was pressed before).

As you can see the infinite loop occurs between the 2nd and the 3rd case. Any suggestion of how I can solve this would be very helpful.

Update:
In the middle part I deleted the part where 'once' receives the value 0, to avoid the infinite loop. (after BT1 and BT2 are set false)

Comment: In your code I am unable to see any loop

Comment: The code in the photo is inside a while loop. I did not post all the code.

Comment: so when do you want to stop the loop?

Comment: Please post the example with the loop

Comment: It is exactly the same thing, only inside a while loop (can not even catch the whole screen in a screen shot). I do not want the while loop to stop (automatically). I just want that the second and the third piece of code do not run at the same time. To be more precise: when I press the first button I want only the third piece of code two execute, and when I press a second button I want only the second piece of code to execute. The main problem is that the 'once' variable switches from 0 to 1 infinitely, and I want to find a way to get rid of that (without changing the rules of the game)

Comment: You should use event handlers and data flow. I think you should invest some time to read before asking.

Comment: Utilise an Event based queued state machine. You can then utilise the timeout on the event structure to pop the pressed button back out after n seconds if another button is not pressed. You would keep an array of buttons(cleared/not cleared) in a shift register in the state machine to help manage when the game is complete. Raise a user event to quit to stop the event loop from the state machine.

Comment: You talk about three different 'cases' but do you mean that the three sections of code above are in three different cases of a case structure, or are they just side-by-side on the diagram exactly as shown in your image? If it's the latter then the code cannot get stuck 'between' them - that's not how LabVIEW works. I strongly suggest you run this code with execution highlighting switched on (the lightbulb button in the toolbar) while watching the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is as follows:

1. Button pressed, Loop 3 runs and sets once to 1
2. No action: Loop 2 runs and sets once to zero even though two buttons have not been pressed.

Depending on the speed of the while loop it may not be possible to notice the change.  Highlight execution is useful here.

The issue with your structure is that the there is no difference between case 2 and case 3, i.e. you could set the cards to have a value, if equal case one if not case 2 and junk case three as two cards not turned.

Rather than use Boolean, use something with a value, e.g. picture controls.

The following uses an event listener to monitor button presses:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are four controls, 2 skull & 2 apple.
If more than one control is clicked there is a check for equality and if true the the controls are hidden, if false they revert to grey.

You can have as many pictures as desired in this scenario,